# How to popup a text field

Tags: iphone, ios4, sdk

I have a view in my app with many labels and a toolbar with some buttons. I would like to edit all the labels at the same time when pressing a button. I thought it might be a way to "popup" a text input and make a keyboard appear at the same time. Which is the cleanest way to do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=8445879

Alternatively. Here's how I do it:

```
UIAlertView *prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please enter your name:"
                                                 message:@"\n\n"
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Enter", nil];

textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 50, 260, 25)];
[textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[textField setPlaceholder:@"Name for message"];
[prompt addSubview:textField];
[textField release];

// show the dialog box
[prompt show];
[prompt release];

// set cursor and show keyboard
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Then in the UIAlertView delegate method you read the content from textField.text :-)

Comment: @Nevin Thanks for this, super easy (for Iphone, that is!) once you think of it. Had to fix a typo in it though, the line [prompt textField]; should be [prompt addSubview:textField];

Comment: Not work for ios7, is there any solution, i want 3 fields, old pass, new pass, confirm pass,this feature i used, but we hv to customize like above, typedef enum {
   UIAlertViewStyleDefault = 0,
   UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput,
   UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput,
   UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput
} UIAlertViewStyle;

Answer (score 10):

I know its too late answer,But this answer for those who are using iOS 5.0 or later.
Now AlertView has new Property AlertViewStyle for various purpose.

```
UIAlertViewStyle
The presentation style of the alert.

typedef enum {
   UIAlertViewStyleDefault = 0,
   UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput,
   UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput,
   UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput
} UIAlertViewStyle;
```

Example:

```
UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"  message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
         [alertView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
         [alertView show];
         [alertView release];
```

Delegate:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSLog(@"%@",[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text])
}
```

Reference : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

Answer (score 0):

This set of codes might help http://d.pr/1Tyt

[image]

Comment: an answer with a link to a site that might not possibly be working later (like now) its not useful